# System.Data Assembly Not found

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, system.data

I have a reference to `System.Data` in my windows service project. I keep getting the `Exception` :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I attach the `FusionLog` to my code and found out the following. For `System.Data` only visual studio is looking here:

> Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll

And it should be looking here (all the other assemblies are but System.Data)

> Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

How can I do point my `System.Data` file to look in the right place?

My guess is `Microsoft Commerce Server` dlls are referenceing the 2.0 folder maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to app.config..

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
```

If you need old versions of dlls to be loaded in a windows service you must add this. For web services iis automatically takes care of it, but not for windows service.

Comment: I have the same problem with my .Net 3.5 project, even had above useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy added. But I can still observe "System.Data not found" exception in Visual Studio output window as first chance exception when debug run. However, except for this, my application runs OK.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your project is set to .Net Framework 4. If that doesn't do it, set it to full profile (not just Client)

Comment: @NickLaMarca Is the full framework installed on the client then?

Comment: Sanity check - can you find the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll ?

Comment: The folder v4.0.30319 is installed on my machine

Comment: Yes I see System.Data.dll here: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0

Comment: Do  you have <startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /></startup> in your web.config?

Comment: I have this in my app.config <startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

Comment: Just curious - are you passing DataSets around through you web service?

Comment: this is a windows service and yes I am calling datasets then mapping them to an object

Comment: That could be your problem, if your client is 2.0 and your server 4.0

Comment: 4.0 is installed on server and client

Answer (score 2):

If you select the referenced assembly in the solution explorer, verify that the runtime version is correct (see image below). You can remove the reference and re-add it to fix it if necessary.

Also, if you are using an app.config, make sure it is targeting the correct runtime version.

[image]

Comment: I verified all System.Data dlls in all projects in the solution have the 4.0 runtime version and the app config is targeting 4.0