# UWP project cannot find System.Data version 4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, uwp, system.data

I'm working on a UWP application and when trying to activate a function from System.Data.Sqlclient this exception pops up:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.'

NuGet can't seem to find the file and I don't know how to resolve the issue.
Has anyone had this problem before?

Just to add information on the specific project:
Its Target version is Windows 10, version 1809 and the Min version is Windows 10, November update (builds 17763 and 10586 respectively).

The most relevant answer I found was in here:
[System.Data Assembly Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641958/system-data-assembly-not-found)
but I could not find an app.config file in my project.

Comment: Note that you can always add an app.config yourself.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue by my reply?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make the project's min version is 16299 or higher. The 10586 doesn't support .NET Standard 2.0.

[image]

The .Net Standard 2.0 has only been supported since the Fall Creators Update (build 16299).